# How to find the equivalent inductance of this circuit?

Tags: inductor, parallel, series, equivalent-circuit

In the image that is given below, I am not able to figure out which is in parallel or in series to what as they are all almost connected to each other. Also, it was given that all inductors are 1mH. Can anyone guide me about how to approach this problem.
[image]

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No, this is a past paper I am trying to solve as my final exams are starting after 20 days.

Comment: That’s effectively homework. Please show your own attempt at solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circuit components are in **series** if they share one node *exclusively*. That is, no other component is connected to the node.

Circuit components are in **parallel** when they are connected to the same two nodes.

I've made an attempt to highlight each of the different nodes in your circuit with a different color. Just apply the definitions above and it should be clear.

[image: Nodes highlighted.]

Comment: Thank you that helped, it was quite difficult initially for me to visualise that the two inductors at the bottom were in parallel.

Comment: @RKEshat Yes, it's drawn in a way to be confusing, but where application of the definitions clears things up. Thanks for the checkmark.